# Python. Why exception 'NameError' don't work?

Tags: python, исключения

All exceptions work, but not NameError, why?

```
def devide (x, y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print('WARNING Devision by zero')
        print(e)
    except TypeError as e:
        print('Only numbers allowed')
        print(e)
    except NameError as e:
        print('Name error, enter correct name')
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('Final block')

print(devide(4,err_name))
```

Comment: Во-первых, это stackoverflow на русском. Во-вторых, у меня работает ваш код с исключением namerror

Comment: @strawdog пишет "Name error, enter correct name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключение NameError выбрасывается на строчке `print(devide(4,err_name))`, а не в блоке `try..catch`. Потому и "не работает".

Если завернуть последнюю строчку в try..catch, то все будет работать:

```
try:
    print(devide(4,err_name))
except NameError as e:
    print('Name error, enter correct name')
    print(e)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Name error, enter correct name
> name 'err_name' is not defined
> ```

Comment: на самом деле ошибка в том, что у человека, задавшего вопрос на английском, функция разделить зовется 'dEvide'